# Natural logarithm method for NSNumber and NSDecimalNumber

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, math

I've got some C# code that I'm converting to Objective-C. In C# I would call Math.Log(). I'm slowly learning that some people stick to C functions/types and only use NSNumber etc when they need to interop with Cocoa.

Is there an equivalent for ObjC/Cocoa, or do I need to drop into C to do this? I need my code to be as accurate as possible because it is part of a calculator.

This code needs to run on iPhones if that makes any difference.

Comment: There is no such thing as "dropping into C" from ObjC. Every C function is an objective-C function. As Alex Reynolds wrote, it's as simple as importing `<math.h>` and calling the `log` function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSNumber` is useful for storage in `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`, or in a Core Data store.

You don't want to use `NSNumber` for arithmetic, only for use with foundation or Core Data classes when you need to store that number somewhere.

This is because you will have to constantly convert between `NSNumber` and primitive types like `int`, `double`, `long`, etc. when performing arithmetical operations. Do the operations with the primitive types to the desired accuracy, and then create an `NSNumber` instance, if you really need one.

Nonetheless, it is fairly trivial to use the C math library in any Cocoa/Cocoa Touch app:

```
#import <math.h>

...

double _param = 7.389;
NSNumber *_result = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:log(_param)];
```

This is the same story for `NSDecimalNumber`, which is a subclass of `NSNumber`:

> [You might consider the C interface if you don’t need to treat decimal numbers as objects](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NumbersandValues/Articles/DecimalNumbers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000176)—that is, if you don’t need to store them in an object-oriented collection like an instance of NSArray or NSDictionary. You might also consider the C interface if you need maximum efficiency. The C interface is faster and uses less memory than the NSDecimalNumber class.

Comment: `NSDecimalNumber` implements some rudimentary math functions. Sadly not logarithms.

Comment: Note that the C interface referred to in the quoted text is for the NSDecimal struct, not your standard floating point or integer types.

Comment: "This is the same story for `NSDecimalNumber`..."

Answer (score 2):

Either you use C's `log()` function which sacrifices some precision as you convert decimal numbers to binary ones. Or you look for a decimal numbers library. [Cocoadev has some suggestions](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?HandlingLargeNumbers), especially the `bc` utility and the [GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library](http://gmplib.org/) library.

Answer (score 0):

The family of `log()` functions is your best bet.  Man page available [here](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/log/).